# iOS Bundle Error for a Unity DLL

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a small dll so I can read in the Pasteboard from my Unity app.

I have the following code:

```
#define MakeStringCopy( _x_ ) ( _x_ != NULL && [_x_ isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ) ? strdup( [_x_ UTF8String] ) : NULL

#define GetStringParam( _x_ ) ( _x_ != NULL ) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:_x_] : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:""]



    //[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"the text to copy";
    //NSString *whatsOnThePasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;

    //send clipboard to unity
    extern "C" const char * _importString()
    {
        NSString *result = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
        return MakeStringCopy(result);
    }

    //get clipboard from unity
    extern "C" void _exportString(const char * eString)
    {
        [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = GetStringParam(eString);//@"the text to copy";
    }
```

However I have the following errors in regards to the UIPasteboard

> Use of undeclared identified 'UIPasteboard'; did you mean
>   'NSPasteboard'?

I've looked in the required frameworks but can't see the UIKit.framework to add it to my bundle. So my question is this:

If I change this to an NSPasteboard will it still work on my iPad as intended? As from what I read UIpasteboard is for iOS Devices and NSPasteboard is for OSX devices or am I completely wrong in that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need `UIPasteboard` for iOS, `NSPasteboard` is for OSX.
If you have downloaded an iOS SDK `UIKit.framework` can be found in:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Remember to change the SDK version in the path.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know how Unity DLLs are working, I guess you just need to link your binary with UIKit.framework